# Why is this function not being applied to a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, one-hot-encoding

I am working with a very large Pandas DataFrame, and want to one-hot encode the "attributes" each row possesses in columns corresponding to each attribute. The attributes are listed in a column "attributes', which I want to iterate through to then target individual columns. At the end, each row should have 1s one the attributes they possess, and 0s for attributes they don't.
With a smaller DataFrame, this function worked:

```py
for i in range(len(df)):
    attributes = df.loc[i, 'attributes'].split(',')
    for item in attributes:
        df.loc[i, item] = 1
```

Now that I'm working with a much larger set of data, my Jupyter Notebook's kernel dies/it takes forever when I attempt this. I have tried to implement an apply() method, but either the kernel dies once again, or the changes it seems to be making (adding "1s") do not persist when I check the dataframe again. I will list the options I've been trying below, if there is something wrong here please let me know, or if Jupyter Notebook is not the right place to be working with lots of data, I would greatly appreciate advice on that too.

Attempt 1

```py
def encode_ones(row):
    attr = row.attributes.split(',')
    row.loc[attr] = 1

df.apply(lambda row: encode_ones(row), axis=1)
```

Attempt 2

```py
def make_one(cell): 
    if cell == 0:
        return 1

df.apply(lambda row: make_one(row.loc[row.attributes]), axis=1)
```

Attempt 3

```py
def change_to_one(row):
    row.loc[[row.attributes]] = 1

df.apply(change_to_one, axis=1)
```

I know confusion about views/copies and chained operations in Pandas is common, which is why I'm using .loc, but am I off the mark here?

Answer (score 0):

> I am working with a very large Pandas DataFrame, and want to one-hot encode the "attributes" each row possesses in columns corresponding to each attribute.

Try using the `str.get_dummies` method on the `attributes` column and see if it performs better with the large dataset.

[link to pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html#pandas.Series.str.get_dummies)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'attributes': ['a, b, c', 'a, c']})
one_hot = df['attributes'].str.get_dummies(sep=', ')

# Add one-hot encoding columns to the original data frame
df = df.join(one_hot)
```

This is the resulting data frame.

```py
  attributes  a  b  c
0    a, b, c  1  1  1
1       a, c  1  0  1
```

---

It looks like your function `encode_ones` should work. Are you seeing out-of-memory errors?

Comment: Thanks Timothy! I'm trying this out now. As for ```encode ones```, I've been trying it on a smaller subset of the df to quickly test it, and there are no errors -- there's just nothing different when I check the df again. I think I'm just getting "Kernel has died" errors, it doesn't explicitly say out of memory although I imagine that's an issue.

Comment: After about half an hour into trying your approach, I got the message "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."